# Which is the best approach? AutoMapper against implicit (C# Reference)

Tags: c#, automapper

Automapper is a way to match types, ideally when you want to map a model and its viewmodel. **But is this not the same approach that we can make with implicit in C#? (Suppose that both model have the same properties but with different names, on this case, you need to specify in AutoMapper which is linked between models)**

With autommaper we have

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeViewItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Usually we do:

```
Employee employee = new Employee
{
    Name = "John SMith",
    Email = "john@codearsenal.net"
}

EmployeeViewItem viewItem = new EmployeeViewItem();
viewItem.Name = employee.Name;
viewItem.Email = employee.Email;
```

with AutoMapper

```
 EmployeeViewItem employeeVIewItem = Mapper.Map<Employee, EmployeeViewItem>(employee);
```

Now, with the implicit C# Reference

```
public class Employee
{
    public static implicit operator EmployeeViewItem(Employee employee)
    {
         EmployeeViewItem viewItem = new EmployeeViewItem();
         viewItem.Name = employee.Name;
         viewItem.Email = employee.Email;
         return viewItem;
    }

    public static implicit operator Employee(EmployeeViewItem ev)
    {
        var e = new Employee();
        e.Name = ev.Name;
        e.Email = ev.Email;
        return e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "better".

Comment: Please don't use `implicit` for this. It'll just introduce bugs. `implicit` is not for this kind of thing. Use explicit conversion methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AutoMapper uses reflection to map properties (slight performance overhead), allows advanced custom rules for mapping and requires 1 line of code in basic (common?) scenarios.

Implicit operators require you to specify each property, are prone to errors (adding a new property but not adding it to the operator), are more difficult to setup for multiple types, create lots of useless code and even in the most basic setup you still have N lines of code where N is the amount of properties.

I think it speaks for itself.

Comment: 2N + 6 lines, actually; you have to map back again, and there's the `return new Foo` and some braces.

Comment: Ok, but what about if you can't put the same properties-names in both models?

Comment: Then both approaches take 1 line of code so there's no difference.

Comment: What about type safety? A projection would be checked at compile-time in the operator case, whereas with reflection, a type error would result in a runtime error.

Answer (score 3):

I say no to this use of implicit.

The viewmodel in this example has no extra properties. However if this really was the case you wouldn't require a viewmodel at all. in reality it would have a number of other properties, possibly containing data not from the original model. eg. IsSelected or something.

The implicit conversion is suppose to work without loss of data and this would not be possible with the reverse conversion back to the model

Secondly!

The purpose of the viewmodel is to match data required by the view. you are supposed to have mutiple viewmodels per model. eg. perhaps you have an edit view and a non editable view. or a mobile app and a webpage!

the model shouldn't know about these views or their models and the use of implicit would require it to be coupled

Comment: At the end, which is your scenario to use implicit?

Comment: I cant really see a scenario for non value types tbh. I don't think I would ever use it

Comment: maybe if you are making your own special value type, StarDate or something maybe

Comment: How does this answer the question? You said implicit conversions should be isomorphic, which i agree with, but that doesn’t apply to the question since the models are *already* isomorphic. And let’s say they weren’t. How is automapper more useful than an explicit conversion?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your particular scenario.

If AutoMapper is capable of mapping your classes onto each other, and you don't need any special logic to happen during the mapping, then why bother writing all that code yourself when there's something out there that can do it for you with a NuGet reference and a couple of lines? Plus, this method will adapt as you change the classes, saving you the trouble of maintaining it.

If you need to do clever things during the mapping that AutoMapper can't do, or for some reason AutoMapper isn't available in your project, then you'll have to write your own operators. If it can be avoided, I'd advise against it, but sometimes you're stuck with it.

Answer (score 0):

Automapper basically allows you:

1. To forget about routine, trivial code;
2. To handle complex type internal properties automatically;
3. To skip (ignore) some properties during copy-construction;
4. Advanced: to create IOC-friendly mapping procedures;
5. To configure 1-3 processes fluently in one place.

But it is obviously slower than handwritten code. So in case you are not concern about performance very much - you should give it a try, it may be worthful. Otherwise you can try something faster (for ex. emitmapper) or write you own mappers by hand and combine to convert complex types.

My experience shows that viewmodels more often are very different from models (DTO's) coz they are created for different tasks, to solve different problems. So automatic mapping would be difficult in such scenarios, оr not advantageous (become unreadable clutter, conglomeration)

Comment: IMO 4 and 5 sound the most useful.

Answer (score 0):

Each solution is good depending on the scenario:

- For source and target objects with properties that have the same names and types, a mapper tool like Automapper is the right choice.
- If the source and target objects have some few properties that have different names or types, Automapper is still a good option as it provides a way to map the properties that do not match (using the ForMember and For Path functions for naming conversion, and type converters and resolvers for typing conversion, as explained [here](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html)).
- Implicit/explicit operators are the best choice when your objects have too few or no properties with common names and/or types (using Automapper you might end up doing as much code as with manual mapping) or when your mapping has sophisticated transformations.

Comment: AM will use those operators when needed, so it's easy to integrate the approaches.

Comment: "Implicit/explicit operators are the best choice when your objects are not very isomorphic or not at all" - What?!?!?