# Copy all fields of one object type to other object type in C#

Tags: c#, .net, object, mapping

I have two objects but having different types. The information stored in them are almost similar, i.e. all field names are almost same in both objects,  its only the type that differs. I want to copy the values of one object to other. The object also have complex types as fields for ex: a list. Please suggest me some library or framework to do that or if there is a native method available in .net C#.

Comment: "Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Have a read of [Which is the best approach? AutoMapper against implicit (C# Reference)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29257215/which-is-the-best-approach-automapper-against-implicit-c-reference)

Comment: Field names are almost same in both objects?

Comment: @Paparazzi Yes! but few complex types inside the object like list are again of different types from other object  but contain the same fields again.

Comment: "only the type that differs" - that is the point which will prevent a "duck copy" approach like that suggested by Adil. With that constraint, there is no general way available.

Answer (score 1):

This code requires some modifications to suit your needs. But overall it looks like.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        classA A = new classA("test");
        classB B = new classB();

        foreach (var field in A.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            PropertyInfo pi = B.GetType().GetProperty(field.Name);
            pi.SetValue(B, field.GetValue(A, null));
        }

    }

public class classA{
    public string name { get; set; }

    public classA(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class classB
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```